# Xamarin-ios Dismiss UiAlertController when clicking outside of it

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm using third party library for AlertView.

Library is linked here -> https://github.com/kvandake/InteractiveAlert-Xamarin

I want to dismiss AlertView when the user clicks outside of it, how I can achieve this?

I tried dissmisViewController but it won't work.
Also, I looked some old StackOverflow questions and tried to do it with 
UITapGestureRecognizer, but it won't work.

My code looks like this

```
 barItem.Clicked += delegate
            {
                InteractiveAlertView alertController = new InteractiveAlertView();
                var text = alertController
                    .AddTextField("MyAltfolio");


                var button = alertController.AddButton("Add", async () =>
                {

                    string value = text.Text;
                    var db = DatabaseManager.Instance;

                    var altfolio = await db.InsertAltfolioAsync(value);


                }, Theme.TintColor, Theme.TextColor);
                alertController
                    .ShowCustom("Altfolios", "Enter name for your altfolio", Theme
                                .TintColor, getImageWithColor(Theme.TextColor, UIImage
                                                              .FromBundle("albums.png")), "Submit", 0, UIColor
                                .Red, UIColor
                                .Purple);
            };

        }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

```
alertController.View.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
alertController.View.AddGestureRecognizer(new UITapGestureRecognizer(() => {
    alertController.HideView();
}));
```